# Why is it that the ball object is colliding with invisible walls when i have specific coordinates to detect collision between the ball and the bricks?

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection

I want to have the ball collide with the bricks individually, on any given side, and to do that ive set up a class to create the bricks and included a function to detect collision between the ball and the bricks, but it ended up creating invisible colliders outside of the boundaries ive set. What is it thats causing the invisble colliders?

i've tried changing the variables and coordinates of the collision parameters to account for the center and top left corner of each brick, in case it was a problem with the coordinates, but that just made it worse. I also tried changing the distance between each brick and had no success on that either. I've also tried running it on different computers to no avail, so i don't think it has to do with an internal software issue or bug.

```
int Posx = 150;
int Posy = 150;
int Velx = 5;
int Vely = 5;
int value = 0;
int BouncePosX = 800;
int BouncePosY = 900;
int BounceLeft = -35;
int BounceRight = 35;
int lifeCount = 3;
int points = 0;
int numBricks = 5;
Bricks[] bricks = new Bricks[numBricks];
```

//Declares variables that will track position and velocity of the shape around the screen//

```
void setup() {
  size(1600,1000);
  frameRate(60);
  for (int i = 0; i<numBricks; i++){
    float x = 10 +(i*70);
    float y = 100;
    bricks[i] = new Bricks(x,y,50.0,30.0);


void draw(){
  background(0,255,0);
  fill(255,0,255);
  rect(BouncePosX,BouncePosY, 100, 5);
  fill(255,0,0);
  arc(Posx,Posy,20,20,0,TWO_PI);
  for (int i = 0; i<numBricks; i++){
    bricks[i].display();
    bricks[i].collide();


class Bricks {
  float x,y;
  float posBrickX,posBrickY;
  Bricks[] others;

  Bricks(float xin, float yin, float posBrickXin, float posBrickYin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    posBrickX = posBrickXin;
    posBrickY = posBrickYin;


}
  void collide() {



        if ((Posx <= x+25) && (Posy <= y+15) && (Posy >= y-15) || (Posx 
>= x-25) && (Posy <= y+15) && (Posy >=y-15)) {
          Velx= Velx*-1;
          points = points++;
        }
        if ((Posy <= y+15) && (Posx <= x+25) && (Posx >= x-25) || (Posy 
>= y-15) && (Posx <= x+25) && (Posx >= x-25)){
          Vely = Vely*-1;
          points = points++;
        }  

 void display() {
   rect(x,y,posBrickX,posBrickY);
}
```

I expect that the collision detection would end up detecting each side of every brick by using the coordinates and determining an area as collided, but so far, its just created random collision zones throughout the screen.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use something like Box2d, since collision detection and physics is not that easy. Simply detecting if a point is inside another isn't sufficient if you want to achieve elastic collision. You have to generate a path/line for each brick at time n and n+1 and find the collision point on this line. Now all bricks are moving at the same time, so it appears they are "jumping" over the collision.

[image: Here is a simple visualization]